# I need explain of a code line of JNI for Android

Tags: java, android, c++

I found this example at GitHub, https://github.com/martinmarinov/rtl_tcp_andro-/blob/master/jni/RtlTcp.c and i want to understand how works. 
I have a Question about some code with pointers.

This is the function's code:

```
static JavaVM *jvm;
void thread_detach() {
JNIEnv *env;
if ((*jvm)->GetEnv(jvm, (void **)&env, javaversion) == JNI_OK) {
    (*jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(jvm);
}
}
```

If the jvm is a pointer how can he uses the operator -> and * together? In my compiler this an error point. Any ideas ?
What means also this "(void **)&env" ?

Thanx

Comment: `JavaVM` is probably a typedef'ed pointer type. So a `JavaVM *` is actually a `SomethingElse * *`.

Comment: The nature of the jvm reference differs between the C and C++ styles of JNI, so your problem may be related to copying code from one type of usage into a program of the other type.

Answer (score 1):

When compiled as C code, `JavaVM` is a pointer type, but when compiled as C++, it is just a struct. From `jni.h`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
typedef JavaVM_ JavaVM;
#else
typedef const struct JNIInvokeInterface_ *JavaVM;
#endif
```

In C++ code, `JavaVM *jvm` is a pointer to struct, while in C code, `JavaVM *jvm` is a *pointer to pointer* to `JNIInvokeInterface_`. 
Then `(*jvm)` derreferences the first pointer, giving a pointer to pointer to `JNIInvokeInterface_`.

Further, `JavaVM_` (C++) defines `jint GetEnv(void **penv, jint version)`, while `JNIInvokeInterface_` (C) defines `jint (JNICALL *GetEnv)(JavaVM *vm, void **penv, jint version)`.

Then we have the following call in C:

```
(*jvm)->GetEnv(jvm, (void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4);
```

While in C++ it is:

```
jvm->GetEnv((void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4);
```

Note that in both languages the `penv` parameter is of type `void**` and it is a pointer to the memory address of `env`.

Comment: But my compiler shows me an error. #if defined(__cplusplus)
typedef _JNIEnv JNIEnv;
typedef _JavaVM JavaVM;
 and the error is : base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JavaVM'